# AngularJS : Directive and $scope and Select Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a directive it all functions okay except the following:

The directive is a basic shopping cart. The directive creates a cartItem which holds a product and has an additional to column qty and subtotal.

The qty column is a basic select element generated using ng-repeat for each product in the cart.

The problem i am having is i can't get the qty value back to my model.

The scope has a property $scope.qty which the select is binded to using ng-model='qty' but the model value never updates.

Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<select name='qty{{$index + 1}}' class='qtySelectItem{{$index + 1}}' ng-model='Qty5[$index]'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
{{Qty5[$index]}}
```

Javascript controller

```
   app.directive('cartItem', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: {
                // products: '=' // Passes the $scope.Products Object
                //itemInCart: '=' // Passes a Scope Object
                //addToCart: '&' // Passes a Scope Function

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            },
            templateUrl: 'Views/Cart/CartLineItem.html',
            function controller($scope) {
      $scope.ProductsInCart = getCartData();
      $scope.ItemsInCart = $scope.ProductsInCart.length;
      $scope.Qty5 = 1;


      $scope.CartItem = [new CartItem()];
      $scope.SubTotal2 = function () {
        console.log('SubTotal2 - Listprice:' + $scope.Model[0].ProductItem.ListPrice);
        console.log('SubTotal2 - Qty:' + $scope.Qty5);
        var result = $scope.Model[0].ProductItem.ListPrice * $scope.Qty;
        console.log('List Price:' + $scope.Model[0].ProductItem.ListPrice);
        return result;
      };

      $scope.Model = formatForModel();

      function getCartData() {
        // ToProductItem(
        var data = JSON.parse(GetSession("ItemsInCart"));
        console.log(data.length);

        return data;
      };

      function formatForModel() {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ProductsInCart.length; i++) {
          var obj = new CartItem();
          obj.ProductItem = $scope.ProductsInCart[i];
          console.log('Product Item: ' + $scope.ProductsInCart[i]);
          result.push(obj);
        }
        console.log('Model Data: ' + result);
        return result;
      };
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Show your `directive` code...

Comment: I have posted the full directive code

Comment: Where are you updating the `model`? If you are updating the model outside the Angular scope you have to call `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` explicitly.